# what happens if I use ³,⨊ this kind of letter for JWT Secret

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, secret-key

I recently conducted an experiment where I utilized unconventional characters such as "³" and "⨊" within a JWT secret, and to my astonishment, the functionality appeared to work flawlessly. However, my curiosity has been piqued regarding the potential risks associated with employing these unconventional characters in such a critical component. Are there any well-established best practices or guidelines for character selection in JWT secrets? I am particularly interested in understanding whether the inclusion of unconventional characters could potentially compromise the cryptographic robustness of the secret, making it more susceptible to malicious attacks. Any insights, explanations, or references to reputable resources would be immensely appreciated as I endeavor to gain a deeper understanding of this subject matter. Thank you in advance for your invaluable assistance and guidance.

Comment: by "the functionality appeared to work flawlessly" you mean you were able to decode the token too? AFAIK the secret is converted to a byte array at one point, so I guess once converted, your special character takes more bytes to be represented than a regular character. It would maybe help if you shared the code you tried

Comment: @Kaddath I tried code `Zlw³Wf7wn0HZt6Lh7no³8Q==`

Comment: And you were able to decode the token? That's surprising because the value you tried is the secret encoded in base64 (easily recognizable from the "==" at the end). Because you inserted the special chars in a base64 encoding, the encoding is not valid and the tool shouldn't be able to decode it (base64 represents information with an alphabet of 64 signs which are letters "a" to "z", "A" to "Z", numbers, "/" and "+"). Your characters are not in this alphabet

Comment: @Kaddath It was originally base64 but I changed some letters to these unconventional characters

Comment: Which should have lead to a "Invalid character" error.. I can't help you more than this without more precisions. Were you able to decode the token with this secret? which tool did you use and what programming language are you using?

Comment: yes I am able to encode and decode tokens with this secret and I dont get any errors I use FastAPI framework